# Google cloud VMs and Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Basically, I'm confused after looking at so many Google Cloud products. I'm starting up a new project that includes a website, an iOS app, and an android app. I've decided to move forward with the Compute Engine as I'll have the flexiblility to do a lot stuff.
I'm thinking of using Cloud SQL for database service. I know that I can install MySQL on my VM. But I'm not sure what's the pros and cons. I'm still researching on this but in the mean time some experts opinion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Go with managed Cloud SQL. Better than doing it yourself and it doesn't cost much.

I'm no expert but I can tell you from previous experience that a managed database solution feels like much less of a hassle than doing it from scratch. Installing and configuring MySQL isn't especially hard, but it can get tedious (especially for devs like me who have done this many times over).

Also, when your app begins to grow, it'll just be a matter of pushing a few sliders to make your DB respond better to all the traffic. Trust me, you can enjoy a higher quality of life with words like "sharding" and "replication" not being part of your technical vocabulary.

Lastly, I don't remember Cloud SQL to be very expensive.